# What is the smallest jump I can make to move through a range, when all jumps are the same length and some positions cannot be landed on?

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

Working through CodeFights. This is problem 4 on level 5 https://codefights.com/arcade/intro/level-5/XC9Q2DhRRKQrfLhb5 :

> You are given an array of integers representing coordinates of
>   obstacles situated on a straight line.
>
> Assume that you are jumping from the point with coordinate 0 to the
>   right. You are allowed only to make jumps of the same length
>   represented by some integer.
>
> Find the minimal length of the jump enough to avoid all the obstacles.
>
> Example
>
> For inputArray = [5, 3, 6, 7, 9], the output should be
>   avoidObstacles(inputArray) = 4.
>
> Check out the image below for better understanding:
>
> [image]
>
> Input/Output
>
> [time limit] 4000ms (rb) [input] array.integer inputArray
>
> Non-empty array of positive integers.
>
> Constraints: 2 ≤ inputArray.length ≤ 10, 1 ≤ inputArray[i] ≤ 40.
>
> [output] integer
>
> The desired length.

The natural method for making this happen seems like it would be step. Here is my code:

```
def avoidObstacles(arr)
  jumps = (arr.min..arr.max+1).to_a - arr
  full_map = (0..arr.max+1)
  jumps.each do |j|
    return j if (full_map.step(j).to_a & arr).empty?
  end
end
```

A clearer way to write this:

```
def avoidObstacles(arr)
  jumps = (arr.min..arr.max+1).reject{|n| arr.include?(n)}
  full_map = (0..arr.max+1)
  jumps.each do |j|
    return j if full_map.step(j).none?{|n|arr.include?(n)}
  end
end
```

I pass all of the visible tests given on the website:

> Input: inputArray: [5, 3, 6, 7, 9] Expected Output: 4
>
> Input: inputArray: [2, 3] Expected Output: 4
>
> Input: inputArray: [1, 4, 10, 6, 2] Expected Output: 7

But I get tripped up on one of the hidden tests. I borrowed a solution from another user, which works in all cases:

```
def avoidObstacles a
    obs = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(false)){|v, h| h[v]=true}
    m = a.max
    (1..m+1).each do |j|
        return j if (0...m/j+1).all?{ |i| obs[i*j] == false }
    end
    m
end
```

I'm not quite sure where this borrowed solution succeeds and mine fails.

Thanks ahead of time for the help. I'm still quite new to coding and appreciate your time.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your logic.  If I understand correctly the returned item should be a number large enough that it is bigger than the difference between each item.  Assuming this is correct, why would the second answer be 4 ... shouldn't it be 2.  First and third seem to follow what I am saying but the second has me lost if it is actually 4.  And your range - array logic has me confused too.

Comment: I added an image to clarify. The (range-array) is done because any member of the array will not be a suitable step interval. I avoid these pointless tests of the step method by subtracting the array from the range.

Comment: I thought of a way to write the code without using array subtraction and union, and I included that in an edit.

Comment: So I see by your illustration you assume the data is sorted and you are avoiding each number, not that the distance between each number needs to be overcome by the size of the jump ... I follow now :)  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
avoidObstacles [3,5,7] #=> 4
```

but it should be `2`. You want

```
def avoid_obstacles(arr)
  return nil if arr.empty? or arr.max == 1
  jumps = (2..arr.max+1).to_a - arr
  full_map = (0..arr.max+1)
  jumps.each do |j|
    return j if (full_map.step(j).to_a & arr).empty?
  end
end

avoid_obstacles [3,5,7]
  #=> 2
```

I changed the name of the method because the Ruby convention is to use [snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for the names of methods and variables.

The other person's solution works because it starts the search at `j = 1`. (It could have started at `j=2` because `j = 1` will always fail.

Comment: So my major problem was assuming that only a value greater than the minimum present in the arr argument would work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in Java using the input constraints given (so did not use input validation)

```
int avoidObstacles(int[] inputArray) {
    Arrays.sort(inputArray);

    //start from 2 because jump length 1 will always fail
    int minJump=2;
    while(validateJumpValue(inputArray, minJump)){
        minJump++;          
    }
    return minJump;
}   

//check if all the successive jumps can avoid touching obstacles     
boolean validateJumpValue(int[] arr, int jump){
    int successiveJump=jump;
    while(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, successiveJump)<0 && successiveJump <= arr[arr.length-1]) {
        successiveJump+=jump;
    }
    return successiveJump<=arr[arr.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def avoidObstacles(inputArray):

    obs = sorted(inputArray)
    jump_dist = 1
    obstacle_hit = True
  
    while(obstacle_hit):          
        obstacle_hit = False
        jump_dist += 1
    
        for i in range(0, len(obs)):
            #### 3%4 and 5%4 and 6%4 and 7%4 and 9%4 =! 0
            if obs[i] % jump_dist == 0:             
                obstacle_hit = True
                break
  
    return jump_dist
```

Comment: this is not providing the solution